# RAD 7.5 supports JDK8.0

Tags: iis, rad

I am using RAD 7.5 and trying to use JDK8.0 in my application . But it is throwing different kind of errors in different files .
Example :

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

So I want to know whether RAD 7.5 supports JDk8.0 . If no , then which versions supports JDK8.0

Answer (score 0):

RAD 7.5 has been out of the market for a couple of years now, so my advice is that you upgrade. Currently, the latest RAD version is 9.6.1.

Now, as for your question, RAD 7.5 is based on Eclipse 3.1, which in turn supports up to JDK 6. You can check details here.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_7.5.5/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-j2se50.htm

Hope this helps.